# Cinnamon / closing two Chrome tabs instead of one

Tags: debian, chrome, cinnamon

Sometimes when I click the middle button (circle) of the mouse on the chrome tab, in order to close one tab, instead of closing one tab, two are closed - this clicked and the neighboring one on the right. Just like I clicked twice instead of one.

How to fix it?

Versions of my software: 
*Debian 9.8 (x86-64) 

Cinnamon 3.2.7 

Google Chrome 73*

Comment: Use an external mouse or run `sudo libinput debug-events` in a terminal to see if it is actually double clicking or not.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @SHawarden

Comment: Cards? Do you mean tabs?

Comment: Yes @muru, tabs.

Comment: I just edited @muru.