# Cinnamon / open folders with single or double clicks

Tags: debian, cinnamon

By default, I have set the graphics environment so that I open folders and files by double-clicking. This is the way that I prefer. However, sometimes folders open at a single click... It is so troublesome that by double-clicking on the folder, the first open the folder, the second performs the action on the contents of the folder - if it is a folder or file, it also opens them, which sometimes it is very frustrating...

How to fix it?

Versions of my software: 
*Debian 9.8 (x86-64) 

Cinnamon 3.2.7*

Comment: try with another mouse first https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/519158

Comment: Alternatively try `sudo libinput debug-events` in a visible terminal and the instant you get the random single-click-opens, look over to check if it registered two clicks.

Comment: Thanks for the advice alecxs and SHawarden